# MaterialDesignDataGridComboBoxColumn ItemSource shares a single instance of a CollectionViewSource when set from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, code-behind, material-design-in-xaml

I have an MVVM application where I am showing a `DataGrid` where the columns are bound to an `ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>` in the view model.

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" util:DataGridColumnsBehaviour.BindableColumns="{Binding Path=TagColumns}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TagList}"/>
```

One of these columns is a `MaterialDesignDataGridComboBoxColumn` from [Material Design in XAML (v2.5.1)](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/v2.5.1/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.DataGrid.ComboBox.xaml) and when I set the `ItemSource` to a list directly all works as expected. However, the list I am binding to I also want to filter, so I have set up a `CollectionViewSource` which uses this list as it's `Source`, and the `ItemSource` of the column is set to the `View`.

```cs
class Model
{

    class AggregateSummary
    {
        public string Id { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Description { get; }

        public AggregateSummary(string id, string name, string description)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Description = description;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> TagList { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> TagColumns { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<AggregateSummary> TagStatus { get; }
    public CollectionViewSource TagStatusCVS { get; }

    public Model()
    {
        this.TagColumns = ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();
        this.TagStatus = new ObservableCollection<AggregateSummary>
        {
            new AggregateSummary(string.Empty, "ALL", "All Statuses")
        };
        this.TagStatusCVS = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = this.TagStatus };
        this.TagStatusCVS.Filter += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var item = (AggregateSummary)e.Item;
            e.Accepted = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Id);
        };

        var tagStatusColumn = new MaterialDesignDataGridComboBoxColumn()
        {
            ItemsSource = this.TagStatus, // works as expected
            //ItemsSource = this.TagStatusCVS.View, // causes all items in the grid to update at the same time
            Header = "Tag Status",
            DisplayMemberPath = nameof(AggregateSummary.Name),
            SelectedValuePath = nameof(AggregateSummary.Id),
        };
        this.TagColumns.Add(tagStatusColumn);
    }
}
```

As noted by the comments in the code, using a `CollectionViewSource` in code behind to populate the items of the combo boxes causes all the items in the grid to update at the same time.

The question is, how do I filter the original list `TagStatus` without ending up with this shared behaviour?

**UPDATE:**

I've tracked the issue down to the style that is applied to the comboboxes being generated for the column. I'm using the MaterialDesign WPF theme (v2.5.1) and the `MaterialDesignDataGridComboBoxTemplate` style declared seems to be causing the value of the first row to appear in all the comboboxes that are generated for the column. There is an [open issue on github](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/1197) describing this same problem.

Comment: What you are asking is quite tricky as the ComboBoxColumn is relative to the Datagrid iteration. One of the method may be to applicate a trigger that do an action (sorting the list) as the ComboBoxColumn does have a modification. I do not pretend to know the best event to use or if it is the optimal way. But at least i give you this lead.

Comment: On a side note, binding to a `ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>` property breaks MVVM. A `DataGridColumn` belongs to the view.

Comment: @mm8 I see what you are saying, unfortunately the columns I wish to display in addition to this status column depend on the data in the model so the columns are caught between view and model. Unless I should be considering a totally different design...